# redis : 40+ servers reading the same redis content

Tags: php, node.js, web-scraping, redis, cluster-computing

I'm gathering sports data every minute with PHP scripts and store them into Redis. It's all done on one ubuntu 16.04 server. Let's call it the collector server.

My goal is to have that Redis generated database available to our customers. The DB will only be read-only to our customers.

The way we connect customers servers to our Redis content is by directly
pointing them to the Redis host: port of that collector server. If all our clients would want to access the DB, I'm afraid the collector server would get stuck (40+ customers)...

That Redis content is updated every minute, and we are the owners of the customers' servers and content.

Is there setup to do in Redis or ways to have 40 +external servers reading the same Redis content DB without killing the collector server?

Answer (score 1):

Before scaling, I recommend that you benchmark your application against Redis with real and/or simulated load - a single Redis server can handle an impressive load (see https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks) so you may be over engineering this.

That said, to scale reads only, read about Redis' [replication](https://redis.io/topics/replication). If you want to scale writes as well, read about Redis [cluster](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

+1 For Itamar's answer. But one more important thing you should keep in mind, letting your customers connect to your Redis resource directly is dangerous and should be avoided.

1. They will have your host:port and password and they will be able to connect, write, modify, delete, and even shutdown or change your password.
2. It is not scalable, and you'll probably notice it when it is already too late and too hard to change.
3. Some customers might have troubles connecting and passing some routers and FW with the non standard TCP port.

You should have an app server(s) that does the Redis communication for your customers.

Comment: We own customers' servers; they are on our side. It's a white labeling kind of business that we do. Clients are just renting our services, they don't add their own code, or servers. So the whole communication steps are on our side. thanks for your answer